# The var retrieved from an array is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code includes an array called buttonColours, a random number of 0 to 3, then the randomColour is supposed to be a random colour in the array of buttonColours, but it doesn't. It classifies randomColour as undefined.

```js
var buttonColours = ["blue", "red", "green"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random * 3);
var randomColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
console.log(randomColour);
```

The console.log only logs randomColor as undefined. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Math.random is a *function* that needs to be called by `()`. Right now you're doing the equivalent of `Function * 3)`, which is of course an invalid mathematical operation hence the result is `NaN(Not a Number)`.

Comment: 2nd line of your code should be                                                                         
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

Answer (score 5):

You'll know directly the problem if you did a console.log on each line :

```js
var buttonColours = ["blue", "red", "green"];
console.log(buttonColours); // ["blue", "red", "green"]
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random * 3);
console.log(randomNumber); // NaN
var randomColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
console.log(randomColour); // undefined
```

The problem is your `Math.floor(Math.random * 3)` is returning NaN, as it should be `Math.random()`

```js
var buttonColours = ["blue", "red", "green"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
var randomColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
console.log(randomColour);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you want to achieve.

If you will try to find out the result of each line you will come to know that `Math.floor(Math.random * 3)` is returning `'Nan'` so the finally when you try to select the element of that position will be `undefined`.

This is returning `Nan` Because `Math.random` is a function and you need `()` to call a function. As you can see in my code it is `Math.random()`

```js
var buttonColours = ["blue", "red", "green"];

var randomColour = buttonColours[Math.floor(Math.random() * buttonColours.length)];
console.log(randomColour);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random * 3);
```

Math.random() is a method, not a property, of the Math object, hence it needs to be ***called***. Calling is done by following the name of the function with a pair of parentheses, so to call a function named sayHello, I would do:

```
sayHello()
```

So to fix your problem, place a pair of parentheses after Math.random, so that line looks like so:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floo(Math.random() * 3);
```

If you want to know what Math.random() actually does, look at [MDN's documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0–1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)...

So essentially it returns a random number from 0 to 0.9999999..., which is why your line of code:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
```

Returns an integer 0, 1 or 2, but not 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a random number within a range by this function. The `Math.random()` return a random value within [0,1). So you have to map the [0,1) with the range you given.

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
}
```

See your solution in this snippet-

```js
var buttonColours = ["blue", "red", "green"];
var randomNumber = getRandom(0, buttonColours.length);
var randomColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
console.log(randomColour);

function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min) + min);
}
```